# unable to start cassandra on windows 10

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql

I am new to this field and was trying to use cassandra (Datastax). I inatlled JDK and cassandra as per the instruction given on their site.

but while I am trying to run CQL shell I am getting below error. I searched to find a solution but couldnt find one.

did re-install the cassandra but didnt help. can you sggest any solution ?

```
    C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\bin>cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})
```

Comment: Did you check the windows firewall has those ports openned? To see which ports cassandra use, check [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureFireWall_r.html)

Comment: In your cassandra.yaml, to which IP do you bind the Cassandra process? Do you really use the localhost/loopback IP?

Answer (score 3):

When installed, DataStax Cassandra adds a service for running the Cassandra Server. However, the service may not run at startup and may refuse to run.

Try the following command:

```
net start DataStax_DDC_Server
```

if you see a message like this:

```
The DataStax DDC Server 3.8.0 service could not be started.
```

Then you are having this problem.

If you are using Community Edition (like me), support has been discontinued so I would not expect a fix in the future.

Meanwhile, a manual workaround is available.

Firstly, append C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\bin to your PATH variable in your environment, to make life easier.

Now open two CLIs (or Powershell windows).

In the first, run the command:

```
cassandra -f
```

Watch the output. Look for a line such as:

```
INFO  nn:nn:nn Starting listening for CQL clients on /<ip address>:<port>
```

The server is now listening for connections.

Leave the first CLI running, and switch to the second. Run the command:

```
cqlsh <ip address> <port>
```

And hopefully it should work.

Addendum: You cannot tab-complete in Windows 10 Datastax Cassandra by default. To fix this, the pyreadline python modules need to be copied into the DataStax-DDC\python\Lib\site-packages folder (copied, not installed. The DataStax python distribution has no ability to install modules).

Answer (score 0):

For 64bit v3.0.9 (I installed through the .msi found [here](https://academy.datastax.com/planet-cassandra//cassandra/)

If you didn't leave "Automatically start DataStax Cassandra Community Service" checked when installing you'll want to reinstall and leave it checked.

**Goto** `C:\Program Files\DataStax Community` and rename the file cassandra.ymal.orig to cassandra.yaml and leave it in the folder it's already in and then start Cassandra CQL Shell.

Note: I don't know if it's needed but I backed up my cassandra.ymal.orig before doing this.

Also, if anyone could shed light on what the command for windows would be to start Cassandra that would be awesome. It seems at least in part this issue is the service just won't start